# netty socket.io How to get socket.io/socket.io.js

Tags: websocket, socket.io, netty

As i can read on the first page of mrniko netty socket.io java server implementation (https://github.com/mrniko/netty-socketio) the client page need to include socket.io.js file.

But if i try to download this last from the Java server the file isn't provided.

So, do i miss something on the java server ? Or do i need to install npm, node.js and socket.io on my server (wich i don't want do do ) ?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to use https://github.com/mrniko/netty-socketio-demo demo project?

Answer (score 0):

In fact, i was already using this file but from another website using it !! That's exaclty what i'm searching for !

Thanks for your response !